# Differention of a First order ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Integrate the ODE:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d \mu(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{5}\mu(t)
\end{equation}

Which we solve to arrive:

\begin{equation}
\mu(t)=e^{t/5}
\end{equation}

Can someone please remind me how to integrate this ODE ?

Thanks

Comment: Separation of Variables gives: $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{\mu}~d\mu = \int \dfrac{1}{5}~dt$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mu'-\frac{1}{5}\mu=0$$
the characteristic equation is
$$r-\frac{1}{5}=0$$
$$r=\frac{1}{5}$$
so the solution is
$$y=ce^{\frac{t}{5}}$$

Answer (score -1):

1. (1/u)du=(1/5)dt

2.ln(u)=(1/5)t+c

3.u=ce^(t/5)